# Site redesign in sitefinity 3.7

Tags: sitefinity

I need to redesign web site that has been done in Sitefinity 3.7. Current version is 6.3 ( I believe ).
I watched some tutorials about this CMS because I use it for the first time.

Can you tell me how much templating system differs in this old 3.7 version from current 6.3?
Is it possible to use Bootstrap 3?

Answer (score 2):

We've been using Bootstrap in all of our recent Sitefinity implementations. I usually end up creating a vanilla, base page template off a .master page that includes references to the Bootstrap css and js, then create custom layout controls through Sitefinity's Visual Studio plugin, [Thunder](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/381fde64-9898-4a5d-ae20-861e119bbf92). Using the layouts you can easily create the markup needed for the grid layouts and components in Bootstrap so content editors can drag and drop them through the Sitefinity page edit interface. Editing the widget templates is another way to incorporate Bootstrap styling in the built in content modules.

[Here](https://github.com/jbokkers/SF-BOILERPLATED) is a project that has a Sitefinity Bootstrap theme, <strike>I believe the version of Bootstrap it uses is 2.31 though.</strike>

#### Update!

Jochem added Bootstrap version 3+ to the project, my fault for not seeing it, sorry Jochem! [Direct link here](https://github.com/jbokkers/SF-BOILERPLATED/tree/master/Twbs)

Comment: Hey Ben, thanks for referencing my Github project. The 'bootstrap' section is 2.3.1 compatible, however the 'twbs' is the bootstrap v3 compatible version... https://github.com/jbokkers/SF-BOILERPLATED/tree/master/Twbs